# Facebook App: add dynamic content to user's news feed

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible  for a facebook app to add dynamic content to the user's news feed?

Dynamic mean that different users will see different message..

Update: in other words an app will publish content that the users will see in their news-feed, yet different users will see different content, e.g. I will publish the weather once a day, different users from different location will see different weather..

Comment: What is this message dependant on? You could possibly just send a direct message to different people, or you could link to a dynamic php image.

Comment: I don't want them to get it as a message, I would them to see it in their news feed, the dynamic PHP image sounds interesting, can you please elaborate? is it allowed?

Comment: I don't think that dynamic(server-side) image will work, Facebook stores a copy of the image..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it's impossible,

The most similar solution is to publish on one's wall. he/she and their friends will see it on his/her news feed...
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

Answer (score 1):

No. Once a post is posted, it's posted, and it'll stay static until it fades from the feed or gets deleted. There's no way to conditionally show certain content to certain users and different content to others. The best way to send different content to different users (as others have said) is to post directly to their walls, so that the message is "to" them. Be aware, though, that it'll be viewable by all of that user's friends.

Comment: no, what I meant is that an app will publish content that the users will see in their news-feed, yet different users will see different content, e.g. I will publish the weather once a day, different users from different location will see different weather..

Comment: Thanks, I clarified my answer a bit - still the same answer in general, I'm afraid.

Comment: that's pretty lame, if it was possible a new type of amazing facebook apps could take off..